# Yii trace - proper usage

Tags: yii

Unit testing and xdebug usage aside, I wish to have a way to throw some browser message is a value is not expected to be present.

Let's say: `$className = 45;`

If we have:

```
public function setMainClass($className) {

            if (is_string($className)) {
                $this->_mainClass = $className;
            } else {
                echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($className),'vardump');
            }
        }
```

We will get this output to the browser on development stage. 
It's great.

I'm not sure however, if this is a proper way of use Yii::trace of if I'm miss using it.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to `echo` the call `Yii::trace()` (it returns void so the echo does nothing). The other recommendation is that you might consider changing category to resemble a path alias as [discussed in the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#message-logging). For example-

```
} else {
    Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($className), 'application.models.MyGreatModel');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Linville. On index.php I've made a function using the trace here. I called quickDump. So instead of this line, I used quickDump($something); I've removed the echo as your suggested. It worked as well. So Yii::trace() seems to deal with echo somewhere else under Yii guts.